# Running ruby gem without building it first?

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I have a ruby gems project with a binary target. Is it possible to run the binary gem without having to install it first?

so instead of running `gem build GEM_NAME.gemspec && gem install GEM_NAME-GEM_VERSION.gem && GEM_NAME [args]` I could for example just run `gem run GEM_NAME.gemspec`?

Comment: What do you mean "run" a gem? A gem is just one or more ruby files. Generally it has a main entry point e.g. `lib/my_gem.rb`, so you could just require that file to test the functionality.

Comment: @engineersmnky What I mean is running a file in the `bin` folder in a way that it resolves the require lines (e.g. requires files inside of the folder specified in the gemspec file, generally the `lib` folder.

Comment: I am uncertain how your gem is set up so I cannot assist beyond this point. If you are altering `LOAD_PATH` to include your gem then `require` should work without issue (otherwise you might need to do this or change the lines to require relative)

Comment: @engineersmnky I've looked up about `LOAD_PATH` and that seems like it will fix this issue.